# Use monogame in Windows Form

Tags: winforms, performance, draw, monogame

I was using windows form to create a game but I concluded that the performance is just too bad. So I decided to work with Monogame.

The thing is that I can't use the tools(picturebox, bitmaps, menus etc..) with monogame so my question is : Can I draw all the things that are normally drawn in monogame in a picturebox in Windows Forms to get the drawing performance of Monogame but still being able to use everything Windows Forms has to offer?

I can't find any information about this topic on the Internet, so I would really appreciate if someone can help me out!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at embedding in a winform. 
http://jaquadro.com/2013/03/embedding-your-monogame-game-in-a-winforms-control/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Answers that are essentially only a link to somewhere else are discouraged on Stack Overflow; what if the page were taken down?